# Exporting Outlook 2007 tasks

Tags: outlook, export, outlook-2007

Hi I'd like to either export Outlook 2007 tasks to a file or access them using some kind of API, preferably without messing around with other Microsoft products. What are my options?

Comment: so VSTO is not an option then? Why do you not want to use another MS product?

Comment: What do you want to export them to? CSV ? 
there are loads of ways to do this can you explain a bit more

Answer (score 0):

You can export/syncronize your Outlook 2007 tasks to Google Tasks using [GogTasks](http://www.gogtasks.com/google-tasks-outlook-sync.php) and use the [Google Tasks API](http://code.google.com/apis/tasks/) to manipulate those tasks. GogTasks is not free but it's just $9.

Another alternative would be using putting your Outlook tasks in the cloud using [Producteev two-way e-mail syncronization](http://www.producteev.com/#emailsync) and then use the [Producteev API](http://www.producteev.com/developers/) to manipulate those tasks.